# Multiple uses of pgfpositionnodelater

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3, latex3, xparse, pgfmath

I'm trying to generate and measure multiple nodes before placing them. Currently I'm using the following macros:

```
% some helper / wrapper commands around \pgfplacenodelater
% #1 = identifier for nodes to be placed later
% #2 = elements to be placed 
\DeclareDocumentCommand \@placenodelater {r() +m}{
  \expandafter\DeclareDocumentCommand\csname mtd@#1-save\endcsname{}{
    % Save Neccesary Registers
    \global\expandafter\setbox\csname mtd@#1-box\endcsname=\box\pgfpositionnodelaterbox
    \global\expandafter\let\csname mtd@#1-name\endcsname=\pgfpositionnodelatername
    \global\expandafter\let\csname mtd@#1-minx\endcsname=\pgfpositionnodelaterminx
    \global\expandafter\let\csname mtd@#1-miny\endcsname=\pgfpositionnodelaterminy
    \global\expandafter\let\csname mtd@#1-maxx\endcsname=\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx
    \global\expandafter\let\csname mtd@#1-maxy\endcsname=\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy
    % Calculate Length and Width as well
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mtd@templen}
      {\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx - \pgfpositionnodelaterminx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mtd@tempwid}
      {\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy - \pgfpositionnodelaterminy}
    \global\expandafter\let\csname mtd@#1-length\endcsname=\mtd@templen
    \global\expandafter\let\csname mtd@#1-width\endcsname=\mtd@tempwid
    % Print Some debug information. 
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelaterbox}
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatername}
  }

  {
    \expandafter\pgfpositionnodelater\csname mtd@#1-save \endcsname
    #2
  }

}

% #1 = identifier for nodes already saved by \@placenodelater
% #2 = location for the node to be placed at
\DeclareDocumentCommand \@placenodenow {r() +m}{

  \let\pgfpositionnodelatername\expandafter=\csname mtd@#1-name \endcsname
  \let\pgfpositionnodelaterminx\expandafter=\csname mtd@#1-minx \endcsname
  \let\pgfpositionnodelaterminy\expandafter=\csname mtd@#1-miny \endcsname
  \let\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx\expandafter=\csname mtd@#1-maxx \endcsname
  \let\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy\expandafter=\csname mtd@#1-maxy \endcsname
  \setbox\pgfpositionnodelaterbox=\expandafter\box\csname mtd@#1-box \endcsname
  \pgfpositionnodenow{#2}
}
```

The process I'm trying to use is something like the following:

- Generate Nodes A and B for later placement.
- Use information about the size of A and B to generate and place C
- Place A relative to the position of C
- Place B somewhere else relative to the position of C

This tends to fail when I am trying to place A with both A and B being placed at once, at the same location. I also receive an error about 
the saved box being missing and treated as 0.

Ideally I'd be able to store the information about a set of generated nodes in an `expl3` l3seq, as a user of my package can define arbitrary numbers of elements, the size information of all of which is used.

Finally, the two `\typeouts` in the first macro don't seem to print anything when the commands are run.

I've got a number of particular algorithms for node placement that I would like to implement but the most common case is the following:

- Have central node C, and 4 directional nodes on each side (N,S,E,W)
- The directional nodes must be directly to their side of C, and C must 
  be wider than both N and S, and taller than E and W.
- The contents of each of the nodes are arbitrary and unknown when the
  macro is defined.
- C should be as small as possible given the above bounds.

I suppose the concrete question here is: How can I use `\pgfpositionnodelater` multiple times in parallel before placing any of the nodes?

I would also appreciate any insight on making the above commands able to handle recursion. I.E. I should be able to call `\@placenodelater` and `\@placenodenow` within the node definition section of another `\@placenodelater` call. This isn't strictly neccesary but would make it orders of magnitude easier on the unsers of my package.

Thank You.

Edit: Here is a more useful minimal (non) working example using the suggestions made by @egreg :

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}% 'crop' is the default for v1.0, before it was 'preview'

\RequirePackage{xparse}
\RequirePackage{expl3}

\usetikzlibrary{
  graphs,
  shapes,
  calc,
  intersections,
  through,
  fit,
  backgrounds,
  positioning,
  arrows,%
  shapes.misc,% wg. rounded rectangle
  shapes.arrows,%
  chains,%
  matrix,%
  scopes,%
  decorations.pathmorphing,% /pgf/decoration/random steps | erste Graphik
  shadows,%
  fixedpointarithmetic
}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

% QUESTION: How can I convert these commands to treat the macro parameters like
%           an expl3 typed parameter? can I do it while keeping the nice xparse
%           syntax? 

\DeclareDocumentCommand \@placenodelater {r() +m}{
  \cs_new_protected:cpn {mtd@#1-save}
   {
    % Print Some debug information. 
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatername}
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelaterminx}
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelaterminy}
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx}
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy}
    % Save Necessary Registers
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-name} \pgfpositionnodelatername
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-minx} \pgfpositionnodelaterminx
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-miny} \pgfpositionnodelaterminy
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-maxx} \pgfpositionnodelatermaxx
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-maxy} \pgfpositionnodelatermaxy
    \box_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-box} \pgfpositionnodelaterbox
    % Calculate Length and Width as well
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mtd@templen}
      {\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx - \pgfpositionnodelaterminx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mtd@tempwid}
      {\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy - \pgfpositionnodelaterminy}
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-length} \mtd@templen
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-width} \mtd@tempwid
  }
  {
    \exp_args:Nc \pgfpositionnodelater {mtd@#1-save} #2
  }
}

% #1 = identifier for nodes already saved by \@placenodelater
% #2 = location for the node to be placed at
\DeclareDocumentCommand \@placenodenow {r() +m}{
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelatername {mtd@#1-name}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelaterminx {mtd@#1-minx}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelaterminy {mtd@#1-miny}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelatermaxx {mtd@#1-maxx}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelatermaxy {mtd@#1-maxy}
  \box_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelaterbox {mtd@#1-box}
  % Print Some debug information. 
  \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatername}
  \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelaterminx}
  \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelaterminy}
  \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx}
  \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy}
  \pgfpositionnodenow{#2}
}

% #1 = Contents of upper box
% #2 = contents of middle box
% #3 = contents of lower box 
\DeclareDocumentCommand \placetriple {+m +m +m}{

  \@placenodelater(upper){
    \node[anchor = south](topnode){#1};
  }
  \@placenodelater(lower){
    \node[anchor = north](bottomnode){#3};
  }
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mts@wa}{\mts@upper-width + 1cm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mts@wb}{\mts@lower-width + 1cm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mts@wc}{max(\mts@wa,\mts@wb)}
  \node[minimum width=\mts@wc](centernode){#2};
  \@placenodenow(upper){\pgfpointanchor{centernode}{north}}
  \@placenodenow(lower){\pgfpointanchor{centernode}{south}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \placetriple
    {The center box should}
    {always be wider}
    {than the top and bottom, regardless of content.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

A somewhat more generic version of the `\placetriple` macro is my actual goal but this produces the same error. (i.e. my actual code lets me pass options to the various nodes I create as well as uses a parameter to generate a name, to facilitate reuse)

The error I get when compiling:

```
.... 
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
not yet positioned@topnode
-52.26361pt
0.2pt
52.26361pt
13.81038pt
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \mtd@upper-box 
l.107 ...e top and bottom, regardless of content.}
                                                  ;
```

I'm not sure what exactly this means, nor why after some fiddling I can't seem to replicate I got it to compile, and display both the center and lower nodes at the same position.

Edit: 
Here's a somewhat cleaned up version of the macro for others who care to use it. It seems to work for the basic use case, however it breaks down when it's nested or when any of the nodes being placed later contain `\tikz[]{...}` environments. (The latter seems to only break after I updated my install of texLive, no idea what's causing it)

```
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Define an identifier and a set of TIKZ commands so that you can get bounding
% box information before you place a node. 
% #1 = identifier for the stuff you place 
% #2 = tikz code you wish to place later
\DeclareDocumentCommand \placenodelater {r() +m}{
  % Debug
  \typeout{Starting_placenodelater_for_#1.}
  % The macro the \pgfpositionnodelateruses as generated by the identifier 
  % given. 
  \cs_new_protected:cpn {pgf@#1-save-macro} {
    % calculate width and height
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgf@tempwid}{
      \pgfpositionnodelatermaxx - \pgfpositionnodelaterminx
    }
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\pgf@temphei}{
      \pgfpositionnodelatermaxy - \pgfpositionnodelaterminy
    }
    % Save all the location registers 
    \cs_gset_eq:cN   {pgf@#1-name}     \pgfpositionnodelatername
    \cs_gset_eq:cN   {pgf@#1-minx}     \pgfpositionnodelaterminx
    \cs_gset_eq:cN   {pgf@#1-miny}     \pgfpositionnodelaterminy
    \cs_gset_eq:cN   {pgf@#1-maxx}     \pgfpositionnodelatermaxx
    \cs_gset_eq:cN   {pgf@#1-maxy}     \pgfpositionnodelatermaxy
    \cs_gset_eq:cN   {pgf@#1-width}    \pgf@tempwid
    \cs_gset_eq:cN   {pgf@#1-height}   \pgf@temphei
    \box_if_exist:cF {pgf@#1-box}      {\box_new:c {pgf@#1-box}}
    \box_gset_eq:cN  {pgf@#1-box}      \pgfpositionnodelaterbox
    % Debug information
    \typeout{__pgf@#1-save-macro_data_:}
    \typeout{_____name___:_\use:c{pgf@#1-name}}
    \typeout{_____min-x__:_\use:c{pgf@#1-minx}}
    \typeout{_____max-x__:_\use:c{pgf@#1-maxx}}
    \typeout{_____min-y__:_\use:c{pgf@#1-miny}}
    \typeout{_____max-y__:_\use:c{pgf@#1-maxy}}
    \typeout{_____height_:_\use:c{pgf@#1-height}}
    \typeout{_____width__:_\use:c{pgf@#1-width}}
  }

  {
    \exp_args:Nc \pgfpositionnodelater {pgf@#1-save-macro} #2
  }
  % Debug
  \typeout{Ending_placenodelater_for_#1.}
}

% Place the node previously specified with the \placenodelater command
% #1 = identifier for nodes already saved by \placenodelater
% #2 = location for the node to be placed at
\DeclareDocumentCommand \placenodenow {r() +m}{
  % Debug
  \typeout{Starting_placenodenow_for_#1.}
  % Move the various variables back
  \cs_set_eq:Nc  \pgfpositionnodelatername {pgf@#1-name}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc  \pgfpositionnodelaterminx {pgf@#1-minx}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc  \pgfpositionnodelaterminy {pgf@#1-miny}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc  \pgfpositionnodelatermaxx {pgf@#1-maxx}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc  \pgfpositionnodelatermaxy {pgf@#1-maxy}
  \box_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelaterbox  {pgf@#1-box}
  % Call into PGF to place the node
  \pgfpositionnodenow{#2}
  % Debug information at time of placement
  \typeout{__#1_data_:}
  \typeout{_____name___:_\use:c{pgf@#1-name}}
  \typeout{_____min-x__:_\use:c{pgf@#1-minx}}
  \typeout{_____max-x__:_\use:c{pgf@#1-maxx}}
  \typeout{_____min-y__:_\use:c{pgf@#1-miny}}
  \typeout{_____max-y__:_\use:c{pgf@#1-maxy}}
  \typeout{_____height_:_\use:c{pgf@#1-height}}
  \typeout{_____width__:_\use:c{pgf@#1-width}}
  % Debug
  \typeout{Ending_placenodenow_for_#1.}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
```

Comment: Without having read the question, this is wrong `\let\pgfpositionnodelatername\expandafter=\csname mtd@#1-name \endcsname`. With `etoolbox` you could shorten all, e.g., `\letcs\pgfpositionnodelatername{mtd@#1-name}` would be working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you're loading `xparse`, it would be better to use the full power of `expl3` for doing that business in a simpler fashion.

```
\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn
% some helper / wrapper commands around \pgfplacenodelater
% #1 = identifier for nodes to be placed later
% #2 = elements to be placed 
\DeclareDocumentCommand \@placenodelater {r() +m}{
  \cs_new_protected:cpn {mtd@#1-save}
   {
    % Save Necessary Registers
    \box_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-box} \pgfpositionnodelaterbox
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-name} \pgfpositionnodelatername
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-minx} \pgfpositionnodelaterminx
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-miny} \pgfpositionnodelaterminy
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-maxx} \pgfpositionnodelatermaxx
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-maxy} \pgfpositionnodelatermaxy
    % Calculate Length and Width as well
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mtd@templen}
      {\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx - \pgfpositionnodelaterminx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mtd@tempwid}
      {\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy - \pgfpositionnodelaterminy}
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-length} \mtd@templen
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-width} \mtd@tempwid
    % Print Some debug information. 
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelaterbox}
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatername}
  }
  {
    \exp_args:Nc \pgfpositionnodelater {mtd@#1-save} #2
  }
}

% #1 = identifier for nodes already saved by \@placenodelater
% #2 = location for the node to be placed at
\DeclareDocumentCommand \@placenodenow {r() +m}{
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelatername {mtd@#1-name}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelaterminx {mtd@#1-minx}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelaterminy {mtd@#1-miny}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelatermaxx {mtd@#1-maxx}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelatermaxy {mtd@#1-maxy}
  \box_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelaterbox {mtd@#1-box}
  \pgfpositionnodenow{#2}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
```

The construction `\cs_gset_eq:cN {foo} \baz` is the equivalent of

```
\global\expandafter\let\csname foo\endcsname \baz
```

whereas `\cs_set_eq:Nc \foo {baz}` is the equivalent of

```
\expandafter\let\expandafter\foo\csname baz\endcsname
```

The difference between `gset` and `set` is that the former does a global assignment, while the latter only does a local one.

Note that your code

```
\let\pgfpositionnodelatername\expandafter=\csname mtd@#1-name \endcsname
```

sets `\pgfpositionnode` as equivalent to `\expandafter` and the following tokens are simply processed as if in normal text.

Similarly for `\box_gset:cN` and `\box_set:Nc`.

Finally, the clumsy

```
\expandafter\pgfpositionnodelater\csname mtd@#1-save \endcsname
#2
```

can become the easier

```
\exp_args:Nc \pgfpositionnodelater {mtd@#1-save} #2
```

---

I fixed the obvious errors in your example code that now runs without errors (but I can't say it does what it's supposed to).

1. A box should be allocated before using it
2. You had an `mts@` prefix that should have been `mtd@`
3. You can't use \mtd@upper-width`as a control sequence name; I remedied with`\use:c{mtd@#1-width}`
4. PGF keys with a space in their name should use `~` (an explicit space) when in `expl3` code.

Here's the code.

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}% 'crop' is the default for v1.0, before it was 'preview'

\usepackage{xparse}
%\usepackage{expl3} % redundant, already loaded by xparse

\usetikzlibrary{
  graphs,
  shapes,
  calc,
  intersections,
  through,
  fit,
  backgrounds,
  positioning,
  arrows,%
  shapes.misc,% wg. rounded rectangle
  shapes.arrows,%
  chains,%
  matrix,%
  scopes,%
  decorations.pathmorphing,% /pgf/decoration/random steps | erste Graphik
  shadows,%
  fixedpointarithmetic
}

\makeatletter
\ExplSyntaxOn

% QUESTION: How can I convert these commands to treat the macro parameters like
%           an expl3 typed parameter? can I do it while keeping the nice xparse
%           syntax? 

\DeclareDocumentCommand \@placenodelater {r() +m}{
  \cs_new_protected:cpn {mtd@#1-save}
   {
    % Print Some debug information. 
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatername}
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelaterminx}
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelaterminy}
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx}
    \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy}
    % Save Necessary Registers
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-name} \pgfpositionnodelatername
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-minx} \pgfpositionnodelaterminx
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-miny} \pgfpositionnodelaterminy
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-maxx} \pgfpositionnodelatermaxx
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-maxy} \pgfpositionnodelatermaxy
    \box_if_exist:cF{mtd@#1-box} {\box_new:c {mtd@#1-box}}
    \box_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-box} \pgfpositionnodelaterbox
    % Calculate Length and Width as well
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mtd@templen}
      {\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx - \pgfpositionnodelaterminx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mtd@tempwid}
      {\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy - \pgfpositionnodelaterminy}
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-length} \mtd@templen
    \cs_gset_eq:cN {mtd@#1-width} \mtd@tempwid
  }
  {
    \exp_args:Nc \pgfpositionnodelater {mtd@#1-save} #2
  }
}

% #1 = identifier for nodes already saved by \@placenodelater
% #2 = location for the node to be placed at
\DeclareDocumentCommand \@placenodenow {r() +m}{
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelatername {mtd@#1-name}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelaterminx {mtd@#1-minx}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelaterminy {mtd@#1-miny}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelatermaxx {mtd@#1-maxx}
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelatermaxy {mtd@#1-maxy}
  \box_set_eq:Nc \pgfpositionnodelaterbox {mtd@#1-box}
  % Print Some debug information. 
  \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatername}
  \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelaterminx}
  \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelaterminy}
  \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxx}
  \typeout{\pgfpositionnodelatermaxy}
  \pgfpositionnodenow{#2}
}

% #1 = Contents of upper box
% #2 = contents of middle box
% #3 = contents of lower box 
\DeclareDocumentCommand \placetriple {+m +m +m}{

  \@placenodelater(upper){
    \node[anchor = south](topnode){#1};
  }
  \@placenodelater(lower){
    \node[anchor = north](bottomnode){#3};
  }
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mts@wa}{\use:c{mtd@upper-width} + 1cm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mts@wb}{\use:c{mtd@lower-width} + 1cm}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\mts@wc}{max(\mts@wa,\mts@wb)}
  \node[minimum~width=\mts@wc](centernode){#2};
  \@placenodenow(upper){\pgfpointanchor{centernode}{north}}
  \@placenodenow(lower){\pgfpointanchor{centernode}{south}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \placetriple
    {The center box should}
    {always be wider}
    {than the top and bottom, regardless of content.};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ooh Shiny. That is orders of magnitude more readable. I need to start using latex3 more effectively.

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't seem to fix my issues, even it it makes them more clear. It looks like `*_gset_eq:cN A B` will not expand `B` before setting equal `A` equal to that value, so that if I change `B` and then reference `A` it won't be equal to the original value of `B` but the new one. However, I don't see a `*_gset_eq:cx` that will do that. Should I create it with the macro `cs_generate_variant:Nn`?

Comment: Never mind, Trying to define those new functions doesn't seem to solve the problem.

Comment: @Jello_Raptor `\cs_gset:cpx {mtd@#1-name} {\pgfpositionnodelatername}` would do, but since `\pgfpositionnodelatername` just expands to a value, there would be no difference. Without seeing some context, it's difficult to give advice.

Comment: I added a minimal working example that should be a bit more useful.

Comment: @Jello_Raptor I fixed the errors that I could see; the example runs without errors.

Comment: Brilliant, I fixed some logical errors (I mixed up the length and width calculations for one) but everything works. I'll clean up the debug and naming in a bit and post working versions of the macros in my original post soon. However, do you have any suggestions on how to structure control sequence names? (is it the `-` that's an issue? what chas should I use in its place if so?)

Comment: @Jello_Raptor You should use token lists and more proper `expl3` coding. Maybe I can look into your final version and suggest some improvements.

Comment: I've gone ahead and posted the cleaned up version of the PGF delayed placement macro. Somewhat annoyingly, i updated my install of TexLive and it broke a number of the higher level macros I wrote earlier, as far as I can tell, now a `\tikz[]{}` environment in the body of a node being placed with `\placenodelater` will fail to display. I was using that feature extensively. I'm not sure about the etiquette here however, should I just add to this question or post a new one?